# Why do I get different results from different credit pricing engines in QuantLib

Tags: python, quantlib, cds

I am trying to use three credit pricing engines: `IsdaCdsEngine`, `MidPointCdsEngine` and `IntegralCdsEngine` but I am getting different NPV results from each of them. The case is like this: When I have as an input same `cds` spread values for different tenors, the `npv` values are different while when `cds` spread values differ for different tenors the `npv` result is similar(still not the same).

I would really appreciate if someone would give me an explanation how do these three engines differ from each other.